# Implementing Sweep and Prune in Java

Tags: java, collision-detection

I am following ThinMatrix's game development tutorial using OpenGL and LWJGL and stuck on implementing collision detection in my game. I have referred to these pages on the web -

- [Broadphase Collision Detection](http://www.codercorner.com/SAP.pdf)

But I don't know any C++ and cannot convert the code. How would I implement broadphase collision detection using sweep and prune in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not quite trivial and probably too much to answer over here but let's try to describe some of the basic steps to get you started.

As far as I remember ThinMatrix's tutorial series you'll have to start with implementing Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes (AABB's) first of all and wrap them around your Entities, since you'll need those for the broadphase detection. You could simply load a `1x1x1` cube model and scale the transformation matrix accordingly, but how would you scale it?

During parsing your obj files remember the minimum and maximum vertex positions (`minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ`) of each model.

You'll then have to rescale your 1x1x1 bounding box, so compute `scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ` of your bounding box and make sure it respects the original Entity's scale as well:

```
float scaleX = (maxX - minX) * model.getScale();
float scaleY = (maxY - minY) * model.getScale();
float scaleZ = (maxZ - minZ) * model.getScale();
```

You'd then have to compute the transformationMatrix and apply your scale-values to the cube. ThinMatrix implemented the method `Maths.createTransformationMatrix(...)` which you'd have to extend with your three new parameters.

At one point or another you'd end up with having an AABB similar to this one:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2duDp.png)

From there I'd recommend to integrate an existing physics library such as:

- [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/)
- [React](https://github.com/flow/react/)

The latter implemented the algorithm described in your linked paper in Java: [SweepAndPruneAlgorithm.java](https://github.com/flow/react/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/flowpowered/react/collision/broadphase/SweepAndPruneAlgorithm.java).